# Visualize Gaussian Mixture Model clusters in MATLAB 

Tags: matlab, plot, cluster-analysis, classification, visualize

I have to write a classifier (Gaussian Mixture model) to use for human action recognition. I have 4 dataset of video, each of them contains 12 action that I want to recognize. I choose 3 of them as training set and 1 of them as testing set. For each frame I extract 907 features that are my observations. Before I apply the GM model on the training set I run PCA on it. So I consider only 50 components.

I construct the GM model with one cluster of each action.

```
gm = gmdistribution.fit(data, cluster_num, 'Options', options, 'CovType','diagonal','Regularize', 1e-10, 'SharedCov', true);
```

Now I want to have a visual feedback to understand if the clustering worked well or the data are misclassified.

Is it possible have something like this?
[image]

Answer (score 11):

I am not near the code I wrote to make these, but I remember which functions are worth looking at.

Start here with [plot_gaussian_ellipsiod](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16543-plotgaussianellipsoid).  You can further add `gmdistribution` and `ezcontour` to end up with something like this:

[image]

Or, for 3d data, you could use `plot3` and `plot_gaussian_ellipsiod` :

[image]